# Existence of preordered coproduct as category

Tags: category-theory

If we view a preordered set as a category, what are the conditions for a product or coproduct to exist within it?

This is mostly a curiosa question that arose as I read and I cannot figure it out.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be preordered set and $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a familiy of elements in $P$. An element $s$ is a product of $(a_i)$, if and only if:

- $a_i \leq s$ for all $i\in I$
- for all $s'$ with ($a_i \leq s'$ for all $i\in I$) we have $s\leq s'$

(That's because: parallel arrows are unique and every diagramm automatically commutes)

You should recognize this as the property of $s$ being a supremum of $(a_i)$. Dually, a coproduct of $(a_i)$ is an infimum. I say "a" or "an" because uniquess is only given up to isomorphism ($a\cong b \Leftrightarrow a\leq b\text{ and } b\leq a$).

Comment: Would you happen to know somewhere where there's a proof? I had a feeling that was it.

Comment: I should also add, does that mean for any $(a_i)$ there exists a product and coproduct?

Comment: @ZelosMalum Just write out the definition of a "product" and see, how it simplifies. It should be rather obvious given my remark ("That's because: ..."). I don't think most authors bother to write an actual proof for this down, at least I can't remember anything like that.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Depends on the preorder. It is not true, that every familiy of integers has an infimum for example.

Comment: I hate that, I always hate that, I had such an enormous hassle writing my thesis because no author would write out a proof I needed

Comment: Would it depend on if they are comperable or not? That is if it's totally ordered or not?

Comment: @ZelosMalum See my integers example. They are totally ordered, but not all infima (or suprema) exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29259/discussion-between-zelos-malum-and-stefan-perko).